# How to call a function from wcalc?

Tags: calculator

`wcalc` has built in constants in functions.

I'm trying to call the `abs` function.

If I input

```
wcalc abs(-2)
```

I get

```
 syntax error
 = -2
```

Unless I enter interactive mode where it works.

Comment: try quoting it: `wcalc 'abs(-2)'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parentheses are special to the shell (they are used for creating subshells).  To use parentheses in the argument to `wcalc` (or any other characters that are special to the shell, such as spaces, filename globbing patterns, redirection operators, pipe symbols etc.), you need to quote the arguments:

```
$ wcalc abs(-2)
sh: syntax error: `(' unexpected

$ wcalc 'abs(-2)'
 = 2
```